# Mail Notification service available in windows azure application

Tags: sql, windows, azure, azure-sql-database

i m developing one application in that one user create one task and that notify to other users which are connected to that user so windows azure provide any notification service to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Azure does not provide a mail relay service, but it does support the SMTP protocol and sending e-mail through external services ; here are a few options:

- Sending Email using Microsoft
  Exchange :
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/10/08/adoption-program-insights-sending-emails-from-windows-azure-part-1-of-2.aspx
- Sending Email from Exchange Online :
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/10/15/adoption-program-insights-sending-emails-from-windows-azure-part-2-of-2.aspx
- Sending Email using 3rd party
  providers (e.g. SendGrid,
  AuthSMTP...)
  http://blog.smarx.com/posts/emailtheinternet-com-sending-and-receiving-email-in-windows-azure

Answer (score 1):

This question is suspiciously similarly phrased to [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/7c852a54-9749-4ace-bbb4-f4f7f6ccf17a). The answer is, there are no notification services that would provide the functionality you seek out of the box.

It also links to the following answers:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/10/08/adoption-program-insights-sending-emails-from-windows-azure-part-1-of-2.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlem/archive/2009/01/08/windows-azure-sending-smtp-emails.aspx

As for the notification service it depends on what you mean by notification. If you want to also pop-up a message, e.g. for chat, or a response to a query, your best bet would be to implement a storage-backed (e.g. Session store with a session state provider, or Azure Tables, even Azure SQL would do) and either print waiting notifications on each page refresh, or better yet, do that with an [Ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Take a look at his [Stack Overflow question for some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219868/client-notification-should-i-use-an-ajax-push-or-poll).

*On a side note*, if you mean notification of services, e.g. a mailer, or something else, that should fire when a user performs certain actions, you can implement the basic functionality using Azure Queues, or Azure AppFabric if you need more advanced stuff.