# Building a chat - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to build a simple chat to my website (Like facebook).

I did everything great but I have one problem, curently the client ask the server if there is new messages in any chat any 2 seconds, and I don't believe my server will be happy to handle 15,000 per one minute. There is anyway that the server will send the client request to update the chat ONLY when there is new message that received?

The whole chat is bulit in PHP, MySQL and javascript.

Sagi

Comment: A Pull request every 2 seconds is pretty excessive; look at push Requests like websockets or COMET

Comment: There is any other soluotion?

Comment: Use node.js :) for the chat or check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/12203443/3284355

Comment: Socket.io? https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io . There is even a chat example there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've used Socket.io with NodeJS cause I didn't see any other option.