# How to use php to recevie notification (remote post) and run javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have web application e.g A, A will generate and pop up B page (a QR code), after the users scanned a QR code, the thrid party server will send a "$_POST" to A application to http://example.com/notify/ , how do i create a php function to echo some javascript (A page will keep opening)?

I've tried added to A application's controller but it is not work

```
echo "success";     
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message was received")';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: If a`POST` request is sent by a third party to your your application, it doesn't make sense to return javascript back to the third party making the `POST`. Can you update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic approaches you can take.

1. Polling
2. Server push

**Polling** is simpler but generally less efficient.

When the HTTP request from the third-party server is received by your server, record the information in it (e.g. in a database).

The page you want to show the result on should use JavaScript (e.g. the XMLHttpRequest object) to make a request to a URL on an interval.

That URL should return the information you stored in the database (or a notification that said data isn't available yet).

*Server push* is more complicated, but more efficient. The browser keeps a connection open to the server and data can be sent along the connection in either direction at any time. This is usually implemented with [Web Sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203443/is-native-php-support-for-web-sockets-available).

---

Either way, you should send *data* along the connection (i.e. *message was received*) and not JavaScript. Have the JavaScript that presents the message to the user be part of the code which waits for the message and not part of the message itself.