# PHP websocket server and JavaScript connection

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, localhost, listener

I have created a PHP websocket server script as following.

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$result = socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 5001);
while (true) {
    $result = socket_listen($socket);
    $client =  socket_accept($socket);
    $input = socket_read($client, 1024);
    $output = 'Input Received: '.$input;
    socket_write($client, $output, strlen($output));
    socket_close($client);
}
socket_close($socket);
```

I've executed file containing above code in terminal using following command

```
$ php server.php
```

Now I want to get the response on my front-end using JavaScript. I've used following JS snippet but not working.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5001/echo");
ws.onopen = function() {
ws.send("Message to send");
    alert("Message is sent...");
};
ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    alert("Message is received...");
};
ws.onclose = function() { 
    alert("Connection is closed..."); 
};
```

Receiving following error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5001/echo' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Comment: You've created a TCP socket, not a websocket. There's a fair bit more to it than that.

Comment: @BenFortune - how to create websocket (ws) rather than tcp socket? or tcp socket able to fulfil my requirement?

Comment: There are plenty of libraries for it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203443/is-native-php-support-for-web-sockets-available

Comment: @BenFortune - What can I do to make JavaScript communicate with TCP rather than creating websocket using 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Nothing. Browsers don't generally support raw TCP connections using JS. You need an abstraction, which is why websockets exist.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a PHP websocket server requires to perform a certain handshake with the client connecting to you via ws:// . In addition you need to decode and encode messages going in and out. The real fun starts when the clients contact you via wss://, then you have to take care of certificate and key within your PHP server and use stream-io instead of socket-io and so on and on. You can have a look at my implementation of all this and use it as another starting point .

https://github.com/napengam/phpWebSocketServer